# DB2 in Oracle SQL Developer - Schema driver error

Tags: schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbvisualizer

I am attempting to access a DB2 database via Oracle SQL Developer.  While I can connect to the database and run SQL code against it, I am having a issue accessing the schema.  I receive the following 3 errors when connecting

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204,
SQLSTATE=42704,
SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SCHEMATA, DRIVER=4.21.29
Vender code -204

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516,
SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29
Vender code -516

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514,
SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.21.29
Vender code -514
```

I am using the same JDBC drivers in DBVisulizer with no issues at all. Rt. clicking on the connection and selecting Schema Browser brings up nothing to select.

Answer (score 1):

I met the totally same errors while using Sql Developer to connect DB2, I figured it out by using DbVisualizer tool, which is more friendly for IBM DB2. Though, this question was posted more than 4 years ago and no one answer so far, hope my first answer would be helpful for new comers. (PS: this is my first answer and post in Stack Overflow as I was always the watcher :) )